# Is it secure that Firebase uid is used / revealed on browser?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am currently building one web application, and I consider to use Firebase auth and its database. My concern is that if user id is on browser, does it make any security issue?

For example, say that my user id is 12345, and I would like to show some information about user 12345 on a certain page. In order to move to the certain page that I can see user's information, I click some element (like a button), and go to the page. (Ex: https://localhost:9876 => https://localhost:9876/12345) In this case, the user id is visible, but I am not sure if this is reliable approach.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed that security rules should be used thanks to Eric's comment. However, I am not 100% sure if the rule can be used for auth object too. For example, auth object is used to get user id, but using user id, is it possible for someone to obtain the user's email address which is stored in auth object? For instance, in the above example, someone might obtain user 12345's email address using user id, 12345.

Comment: You have to implement the Security Rules for it to be secure.

Comment: I added some questions based on your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to secure user related resources is via a Firebase ID token. Database/Storage rules already rely on this mechanism. You cannot just rely on the correct user ID being provided. That provides no security. Instead, before return restricted resources, you should check verify the ID token and trust only its content which includes the UID. FYI: the Firebase Admin SDKs already provide an API to verify an ID token.
Typically the way to pass the ID token (if you are not using real-time database), is as follows:

1. Single page app: you can call getIdToken() and then pass the latest ID token in the URL query parameter, post body or the header as you send an XHR request to your server.
2. Traditional website: you have to set a session cookie. The easiest way is to set the ID token as session cookie and keep updating it on expiration. On your backend, you will verify this before returning the user specific resource.

Comment: It looks like I can use [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_in_existing_users) on browser if I would like an easier way. And for backend, I may consider [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). Thanks for your advice!